# Reemplazo caracteres de un campo en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi duda es la siguiente,

Tengo un campo llamado `titulo` cuyos registros son todos nombres de títulos universitarios. Algunos contienen `ñ`, otros letras con tildes. Eso lo importé de un `csv` que ya venia con errores y mi intención es depurarlos e insertarlos limpios en una columna nueva de la misma tabla llamada `TituloDepurado`.

**Ejemplo:**

`Titulo` profesorado de EducaciÃ³n FÃ­sica

`TituloDepurado`
profesorado de Educación Física

Realicé un *Stored Procedure* con la función *replace*.
No me marca error al ejecutarse pero sin embargo me inserta en la nueva columna los nombres tal cual estaban, sin ninguna modificación.

La sentencia de los *updates* es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = REPLACE(titulo, "Ã¡", "á") 
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = REPLACE(titulo, "Ã©", "é") 
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = REPLACE(titulo, "Ã­", "í") 
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = REPLACE(titulo,"Ã³", "ó") 
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = REPLACE(titulo, "Ãº", "ú") 
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = REPLACE(titulo,"Ã±", "ñ")
```

Me gustaría saber por qué inserta los títulos en la nueva columna tal cual están sin hacer caso de la función `replace`.

¿Cuál sería mi error?

Comment: Tus update no alcanzan a ningún registro ya que falta una cláusula WHERE... Pero ¿Por qué se insertaron mal? ¿Será que el encodaje de la base de datos no es utf-8? Deberías revisar eso para que no sigas teniendo problemas en el futuro.

Comment: @A. Cedano, creo que la intención del OP es afectar a todos los registros. Si no se utiliza el WHERE actualiza todos los registros de la tabla. Saludos!

Comment: En realizad no añadi la clausula WHERE ya que necesito que el set sea para todos los registros de la tabla, simplemente que cuando encuentre ese caracter raro lo transforme al correspondiente, el update se realizo bien pero se inserto en **titulodepurado** exactamente igual que como estaba en **titulo** sin hacer caso a los dos argumentos finales de la funcion replace!

Comment: Entendido. De todos modos una función replace como la que tienes ayudaría poco, debes revisar el encodaje de tu base de datos, de lo contrario, las futuras inserciones tendrán el mismo problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>[Función extraída desde Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412587/3200493)</sub>

Lo único que requieres es decodificar el texto a UTF-8 por medio de una función:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DecodeUTF8String(@value varchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Transforms a UTF-8 encoded varchar string into Unicode
    -- By Anthony Faull 2014-07-31
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max);

    -- If ASCII or null there's no work to do
    IF (@value IS NULL
        OR @value NOT LIKE '%[^ -~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
    )
        RETURN @value;

    -- Generate all integers from 1 to the length of string
    WITH e0(n) AS (SELECT TOP(POWER(2,POWER(2,0))) NULL FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL)) e(n))
        , e1(n) AS (SELECT TOP(POWER(2,POWER(2,1))) NULL FROM e0 CROSS JOIN e0 e)
        , e2(n) AS (SELECT TOP(POWER(2,POWER(2,2))) NULL FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 e)
        , e3(n) AS (SELECT TOP(POWER(2,POWER(2,3))) NULL FROM e2 CROSS JOIN e2 e)
        , e4(n) AS (SELECT TOP(POWER(2,POWER(2,4))) NULL FROM e3 CROSS JOIN e3 e)
        , e5(n) AS (SELECT TOP(POWER(2.,POWER(2,5)-1)-1) NULL FROM e4 CROSS JOIN e4 e)
    , numbers(position) AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(DATALENGTH(@value)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM e5
    )
    -- UTF-8 Algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
    -- For each octet, count the high-order one bits, and extract the data bits.
    , octets AS
    (
        SELECT position, highorderones, partialcodepoint
        FROM numbers a
        -- Split UTF8 string into rows of one octet each.
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT octet = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@value, position, 1))) b
        -- Count the number of leading one bits
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT highorderones = 8 - FLOOR(LOG( ~CONVERT(tinyint, octet) * 2 + 1)/LOG(2))) c
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT databits = 7 - highorderones) d
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT partialcodepoint = octet % POWER(2, databits)) e
    )
    -- Compute the Unicode codepoint for each sequence of 1 to 4 bytes
    , codepoints AS
    (
        SELECT position, codepoint
        FROM
        (
            -- Get the starting octect for each sequence (i.e. exclude the continuation bytes)
            SELECT position, highorderones, partialcodepoint
            FROM octets
            WHERE highorderones <> 1
        ) lead
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT sequencelength = CASE WHEN highorderones in (1,2,3,4) THEN highorderones ELSE 1 END) b
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT endposition = position + sequencelength - 1) c
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            -- Compute the codepoint of a single UTF-8 sequence
            SELECT codepoint = SUM(POWER(2, shiftleft) * partialcodepoint)
            FROM octets
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT shiftleft = 6 * (endposition - position)) b
            WHERE position BETWEEN lead.position AND endposition
        ) d
    )
    -- Concatenate the codepoints into a Unicode string
    SELECT @result = CONVERT(xml,
        (
            SELECT NCHAR(codepoint)
            FROM codepoints
            ORDER BY position
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)');

    RETURN @result;
END
GO
```

Después, pasar el texto a decodificar en la función. Por ejemplo, el texto `EducaciÃ³n FÃ­sica`:

```
SELECT dbo.DecodeUTF8String('EducaciÃ³n FÃ­sica')
```

Tendrá como salida:

> `Educación Física`

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración y el resultado](http://rextester.com/UCJ82225)</kbd>

En tu caso, simplemente es hacer el `UPDATE` de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE tabla set TituloDepurado = dbo.DecodeUTF8String(titulo)
```

Comment: Me funciono a la perfeccion, incluso mejor de lo que esperaba, no conocia eso de codificacion y decodificacion asi que me fue de muchisima ayuda.

Comment: Buen día. Esto funcionara tambien para todos los datos de todas las tablas de una base de datos?
No soy experto en el tema. Gracias!

Comment: @Pablo siempre y cuando sea una base de datos SQL Server y los campos sean de tipo `VARCHAR`